# Visual Studio 2022 Metadata file could not be found

Tags: blazor, webassembly, visual-studio-2022

I have a big problem in Visual Studio 2022 :
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0006  Metadata file 'BlazorAppTestNET6\BlazorAppTestNET6\Client\obj\Debug\net6.0\ref\BlazorAppTestNET6.Client.dll' could not be found BlazorAppTestNET6.Server    BlazorAppTestNET6\BlazorAppTestNET6\Server\CSC  1   Active

### I spent already a few days to solve this problem and I think I tried everything found on the internet :
1.Clean All Projects.
2.Unload All Projects.
3.Reload All Projects.
4.ReBuild Solution

1. Right-click on the solution and click Properties.
2. Click Configuration on the left.
3. Make sure the check box under "Build" for the project it can't find is checked. If it is already checked, uncheck, hit apply and check the boxes again.
4. (Optional) You had to do it for both Release and Debug modes on the solution properties.

---

### I deleted the hidden .VS folder and rebuild.

### I deleted the hidden .suo file and rebuild.

I deleted OBJ and BIN folders and rebuild.

And nothing worked !
I still get the same error and I cannot run my project !

Can you help me, please ?

Thank You Very Much !